# как загрузить видео в google colab

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, anaconda, google-colaboratory

Можно ли в google colab загружать видео? Хочу чтобы нейросеть определяла, есть ли на видео кошка, например.

Answer (score 1):

На текущий момент, Вы можете размещать файлы на Google Drive
Обращаться к диску,

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Вы его там увидите, напрямую или скачивать с него.
Можно так же постоянно предварительно скачивать файлы с другим мест на  локальный Colab диск среды, коротая Вам дается. Много времени это не занимает.
А вот отображением больших видео более 10Мб (если хотите на видео найденного кота посмотреть в Colab) нужна нормальная прямая URL ссылка на файл, которую получить трудно.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]